# how can I use ionicons 7 in an electron react app?

Tags: reactjs, svg, sass, electron, ionicons

I have an electron app (with react) that currently uses ionicons 5.2.3.  In my project I found an `scss` folder with a subfolder `ionicons` which has a set of `.scss` files.

However, I'd like to upgrade to ionicons 7 because it has some icons I want.

So, I removed ionicons from the project (`yarn remove ionicons`), then added it back to get the latest version (`yarn add ionicons`).  I renamed my scss\ionicons folder, then copied node_modules\ionicons\dist\ionicons into my scss folder.  However, that new ionicons folder doesn't have scss files, it has svg files.  But in a fit of optimism, rebuilt the app anyway.  Result:  I still only get the old icons showing up in my app.

For example, `<ion-icon name={'clipboard-sharp'} />` shows the icon (which was available in my old ionicons 5.2.3), but `<ion-icon name={'chevron-collapse-sharp'} />` does not show the icon (which is available in the current version of [ionicons](https://ionic.io/ionicons)).

How do I get icons from ionicons 7 to actually show up in my app?

Comment: Why would you copy the code of a dependency? What's the point of installing it as dependency if you do that?

Comment: @Arkellys I'm not sure, maybe a fast way to make small changes, without forking?  Though I'm not aware of any changes made.  I inherited this code base.  I just assumed this was the way you were supposed to use ionicons v.5, since it was working in this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have it working:

- I removed ionicons:  `yarn remove ionicons`
- I added ionicons to get the latest version:  `yarn add ionicons`
- I added @ionic/react:  `yarn add @ionic/react`
- in my `scss` folder, I renamed the `ionicons` folder to `ionicons-5.2.3`

In my Icon component:

- `import * as IonIcons from 'ionicons/icons';`
- ```
    const icon = IonIcons[children];

    if (!icon) {
      // use the old ionicons 5.2.3
      return <IonIcon style={style} name={children} />;
    }
    // use the new ionicons
    return <IonIcon style={style} icon={icon} />;
  ```

Note that for ionicons 5, use hyphens:  `<Icon>volume-high-outline</Icon>`.

For ionicons 7, use camelCase:  `<Icon>removeSharp</Icon>`